# How to pass bash argument array to single-quoted python call

Tags: python, bash

I have a script that looks something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/myproc --tags='env:dev' 'python myscript.py --my-argument VAL1 --my-argument VAL2 > /some/redirect'
```

Now I need to add additional logic that conditionally changes the arguments passed to my python script. So I've tried pulling the script call into a bash function and passing the arguments from bash to python like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

callMyScript () {
  /usr/local/bin/myproc --tags='env:dev' 'python myscript.py "$@" > /some/redirect'
}

if [ $1 = "foo" ]
then
  callMyScript --myargument VAL1 --myargument VAL2
else
  callMyScript --myargument VAL3 --myargument VAL4 --my-argument VAL5
fi
```

Unfortunately my arguments aren't making it to my python script at all. I've tried several different approaches to string interpolation, array expansion, and quote wrapping but I'm coming up empty handed. The arguments are either missing, sent as one arg instead of separate args, or something even weirder.

This is a simplified version of the real thing, of course, but the root of my troubles seems to be that my python call is wrapped in single quotes and that's not something I can find a way around.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 seems relevant. What is `myproc`, and why does it need to take an arbitrary shell command as a single string argument?

Comment: The arguments to `/usr/local/bin/myproc` do not need to be in single-quotes. If you used double-quotes instead, you might have to escape some special characters inside the string, but other than that it'd do the exact same thing as the single-quoted version. In fact, in your first example, you could just replace the single-quotes with double-quotes, and it would not make *any* difference -- the exact same arguments would be passed to `/usr/local/bin/myproc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the arguments expanded to a single string, use `"$*"` over `"$@"`.

```
callMyScript () {
  /usr/local/bin/myproc --tags='env:dev' 'python myscript.py '"$*"' > /some/redirect'
}
```

When `"$@"` is expanded within a word, the part of the word before it gets prepended to the first argument and the part of the word after it gets appended to the last argument. You still get a list of multiple words at the end of it, when what you really want is a single word with all the arguments inside of it.

See [special parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) for more information.

(Note: [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) will also catch this - `'python myscript.py '"$@"' > /some/redirect'` produces `Argument mixes string and array. Use * or separate argument.`)

Comment: OP likely does *not* want all the arguments specified as a single argument to Python.

Comment: If you look at their static example it passes the whole python command to `/usr/local/bin/myproc` as a single string. I expect they want to reproduce that behavior with the function arguments.

Comment: Suppose the two arguments are `foo bar` and `baz`. You need to construct somethign like `python myscript 'foo bar' baz`, not `python myscript foo bar baz`.

Comment: @chepner: OP here. I do indeed want it as a single string because it's getting passed to another process as tjm correctly pointed out. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: You want `myproc` to get a single string. That doesn't mean that string should be constructed from `$*`, which will erase the distinction between whitespace *in* an argument and whitespace that *separates* arguments.

Comment: If `myproc` is passing the string to a shell or shell-like interpreter then that's trivially resolvable with embedded escapes. If it's doing something more complex then that's probably worthy of its own question.

Comment: @chepner Maybe you'd like to post your own answer instead of continuing to tell this person what you don't like about their answer?

Comment: @Splendor Because the OP has not provided enough information to answer the question properly, IMO.